# Python SCPI avoiding fixed delays (synchronization issue)

Tags: python

I am using a Agilent 4155C Semiconductor Parameter Analyzer. I am having a controller/device synchronization issue. I am using python PyVisa to `write` SCPI commands to it. I am also reading data straight from the machine by using PyVisa's `query` command.

The issue is that as many of you may know, if you send a query command to a system before its finished all its operations, the system spits out a timeout/query interupted error. I read from this manual ([Manual Link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiRifbHpq3NAhXDSSYKHSGoB3oQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rohde-schwarz.de%2Ffile%2F1GP79_1E_SCPI_Programming_Guide_SigGens.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEWeIgBFxDwot1CrAYhiZnXi_lRag&sig2=aLChYbvuaX0bhJK6-hvz2g&cad=rja)) (Specifically **pages 10-12**) and found that people use a for loop with the `*CLS`, `*OPC`, and `*ESR?` commands with a sleep command to check manually if all operations are complete.

The code below is a portion of the code I am trying to run. The proposed solution from the manual has no become the problem because I cannot send the `*ESR?` query command without timing out either.

Note: The timeout error pops up at `instr.query("*ESR?")` line.

```
...
instr.write(":FORM:DATA ASC")

instr.write("*CLS")
instr.write("*OPC")
ESRvalue = 0

while (ESRvalue & 1) == 0:
    instr.query("*ESR?")
    time.sleep(0.01)

I_unicode_data = instr.query(":DATA? 'ID' ")

V_unicode_data = instr.query(":DATA? 'VD' ")

I_raw_data = I_unicode_data.encode('utf-8')

V_raw_data = V_unicode_data.encode('utf-8')
...
```

Comment: You could try `instr.query(":FORM:DATA ASC; *STB?")` that should return when the operation has completed. The value of `*STB?` should also indicate if some error occurred.